# How can disable wordpress emails notifications?

Tags: php, functions, email

How can disable WordPress emails notifications?

- Your email change.
- New user registration email.
- Password change email.

I found many solutions but it's too old.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins available for manage email notification one of them

[Better Notifications for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/)

Please check other if you want.

Comment: yes but i need to make it without using plugin have any idea how can make it by codes inside function php?

Comment: For this please check this document http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-automatic-update-email-notification-in-wordpress/

Comment: I already try this but it's not woking you can try by your self.